# Change "Linked function" to "bind" or "on"

Tags: javascript, function

I don't know how is this called:

```
function eliminarLinea(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(".linea").length==1)
        alert("No se pueden eliminar todas las líneas");
    else
        $(this).parents(".linea").remove();

    reordenarNumerosLineas();
}

$(".eliminaLinea").click(eliminarLinea);
```

But some elements .eliminaLinea are created dinamically and $(".eliminaLinea").click(eliminarLinea); stop working. I need to do this but with a "on" or "bind".

Something like 
    $('.eliminarLinea').bind('click', eliminarLinea(event));
    or
    $(".eliminarLinea").bind("click", eliminarLinea);

But it's not working. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate the event. Something like this should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '. eliminaLinea', eliminarLinea);
```

Since we don't know your markup, I have bound the event to `document`, but you should note that this is very inefficient. It'd be better to use the nearest (non-dynamic) container.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.on` with a selector to use "event delegation":

```
$(document).on('click', '.eliminaLinea', eliminarLinea);
```

Note that using `document` is inefficient - if at all possible specify a closer (non-dynamic) ancestor.

The given element is the one that actually has the event handler bound to it (hence why it must be an existing element) but when the event is triggered it'll bubble from the true event target and jQuery then checks whether it matches the given selector.

Comment: Thank you, works perfect. I set my table id instead of document.

Comment: My answer was to both of you, but i'm new at stackoverflow and confused the button to do that. The vote goes to BenM because it was faster than you. Sorry, both are good answers

Comment: @CarlosGoce they were pretty much simultaneous, but then he pretty much copied the text about not using `$(document)` from mine.